# french localization of windows dialog boxes

Tags: c#, .net

My application (developed using Winform C#) supports localization. I use some windows dialog boxes (like print dialog box, Color dialog box) which appear in English only. Please let me know if there is any way to change the languag of these dialog boxes.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: aren't this dialog following the system language? If I'm right, I don't think you can change them.

Comment: I think so , just wanted to know if there is any way to change/override.

Comment: You can safely assume that any user that habitually yells "Merde!" at his machine will have dialogs that talk back in French.  If it really matters then you can get the French version of Windows from an MSDN subscription or by purchasing a license for Windows Ultimate, installing the French language pack and switching the system locale.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any thing as all system dialogues should change accordingly with the OS language and cultural settings.